# 'Can not create a Path from an empty string' Error for 'CREATE TABLE AS' in hive using S3 path

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, hive, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I am trying to create a table in Glue catalog with s3 path location from spark running in EMR using hive. I have tried the following commands, but getting the error:

> *pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an
> empty string;'*

`sparksession.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/test/' as (SELECT * from my_table)")`

`sparksession.sql("CREATE TABLE abcSTORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/test/' AS select * from my_table")`

`sparksession.sql("CREATE TABLE abcas SELECT * from my_table USING PARQUET LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/test/'")`

Can someone please suggest the parameters that I am missing?

Comment: BTW you do not need the last slash in the path. `LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/test'`

Comment: It still doesn't work. The error is the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue happens when a database is created without specified location:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

To fix the issue, specify location when create database:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/db_path';
```

Then, create a table:

```
USE db_name;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/db_path/abc' as (SELECT * from my_table)
```

Comment: In a AWS Glue Job, this error message was written in errors logs, In my case i added the path to de database in AWS Glue data catalog  and after that the error was solved