# Can not create a Path from an empty string when using hive 3

Tags: hadoop, hive

I run the following hive sql on hive 3, and it throw error of `Can not create a Path from an empty string`, but the same sql works on hive 2, anyone know why ? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people_csv (id int, name string) 
PARTITIONED by (dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: may be you need to add a `LOCATION` because default location is not defined in hive3

Comment: Read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001452/2700344